# Sending TCP Packet

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcp

I'm trying to send a packet to a Tattile traffic camera.
The Tattile camera uses its own TCP packet protocol called TOP (Tattile Object Protocol)
So far from what I can see from reading the documentation I need a 
`IP` > `TCP` > `TOP HEADER` > `VCR PAYLOAD`
[image: TCP Commmunication]
To create the `TOP Header`
Here are the requirements.
[image: TOP HEADER]
24 bytes are required I believe.
[image: Command Header]
Here is the command header, from the image above, the `Header Dimension` part, is this asking for the `TOP Header` that required 24 bytes?
[image: Header Constructor]
Here is the `Header Constructor` which I dont understand why it is there is there is already a `Command Header` with the same information from what I can see.
[image: Building A Message]
Here is an example on building a message, so for the `command code` at this stage until I get a better understanding, all I want to do is send data, not receive, so with that being said
[image: Start Engine]
Here is the `Start Engine` command code.
Here is what I have code wise, so far it connects and "sends the message" however the engine doesn't start, as for the `enum` in the future when I get a better understanding, I should be about to add more of the commands with the command codes.

```
class Command
{
    public enum Codes
    {
        START_ENGINE
    }

    private static readonly byte[] HeaderDimension = new byte[24];
    private static byte[] CommandCode;
    private static readonly byte[] Sender = new byte[4] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
    private static readonly byte[] Receiver = Sender;
    private static readonly byte[] Error = new byte[] { 0 };
    private static readonly byte[] DataDimension = new byte[] {0};

    public static void Execute(Codes code)
    {
        if (code == Codes.START_ENGINE)
        {
            CommandCode = new byte[4]{ 0x35, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4};
        }

        using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("192.168.1.21", 31000))
        {
            NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] bytesTosend = HeaderDimension.Concat(CommandCode)
                                                .Concat(Sender)
                                                .Concat(Receiver)
                                                .Concat(Error)
                                                .Concat(DataDimension).ToArray();

            networkStream.Write(bytesTosend, 0, bytesTosend.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm calling it

```
static void Main()
{
    Command.Execute(Command.Codes.START_ENGINE);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I find it highly doubtful that `0x35, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4` is the correct way to encode the command `35004`. How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I came to that conclusion because it wants the command in a byte array I think

Comment: But the documentation seems comfortable with using hex notation in other places. If 35004 is (without any other indication) to be interpreted as hex, conventionally that would be encoded as `0x00, 0x03, 0x50, 0x04`. But since it looks like a plain decimal, you'd normally encode that number as `0x00, 0x00, 0x88, 0xBC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header has a total of 24 bytes, containing 6 x 4 byte values. The first 4 bytes contain the length, being 24 (0x18). In C# these are Int32 data types, however keep in mind what the byte order is. Network protocols usually have network byte order (big indian) which is likely different from your C#. Use the System.BitConverter class to test and change if needed.

Comment: No, the header should likely be { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18 }. You need to check the TOP specs to see if they use big-endian.

Comment: Ohhh I see so whenever it’s an array of say 5 but it asks for only an input of 24, you lead by 0x0 until the place place holder?

Comment: In theory, when it's a big endian system, yes. For a little endian system it's the other way around, start with 0x05 and add 4 0x00's. But usually it's 2 bytes, 4 bytes or 8 bytes, not 5 bytes.

Comment: Almost. It would look like 0x06, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x00.

Comment: Use the System.BitConverter class and don't store 32bit signed integers values as a 4-byte array but as an Int32. Only convert if the BitConverter IsLittleEndian == false tells you so.

Comment: That's the correct result isn't it? 6 47 0 0 == 0x06 0x2F 0x00 0x00.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173705/discussion-between-ton-plooij-and-andrewe).

Answer (score 1):

Your `HeaderDimension` should be a 4-byte array that *contains* the value 24, not a 24-byte array.

Also the `Error` and `DataDimension` should always be 4 bytes in length.